# ORM [OGM] to use for neo4j-django integration?

Tags: django, neo4j

I wanted to develop a web app using Django, but I decided to use Neo4j as my database since the project is related to social media. As it has been the case, Neo4j is not supported for Django, and I should use ORMs to enable that. Neo4Django was my first sight, but it only support outdated Neo4J (1.9.4.) & Django (1.5) versions. Is there any other suggestions besides that to move on with Neo4j-Django? Any examples on using neo4restclient for django app? Specially on how to set the database on the settings.py?

Neo4J = 2.x, Django > 1.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shameless plug, you may find neomodel fits your needs: http://neomodel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

It's got some level of django integration but isn't tied to the framework its self.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. I looked into the ORM before, and found this http://nigelsmall.com/py2neo/1.6/neomodel/ ... but I have no idea on how to configure the database in Django. Is there any useful tutorials for how to use it with Django? I did also find this link of a complete list, which could be useful for anyone interested. http://neo4j.com/developer/python/

Comment: Never mind. That works. I am now looking to see if the relationship properties supported. Thanks a lot for the quick response & THE ORM. (going by the use of Shameless plug, I take it you're one of the developers)

Comment: Hi yes! I am the original author of the module however theres over 20 contributors :-) There is no django specific tutorial as such but I would be happy to add one